# How can I crop every page of a large PDF file?

Tags: windows, macos, pdf, scanning

I have a 1300 page PDF file of a scanned book that was unfortunately not cropped when scanned. The actual book page dimensions are around 6x9", but each scanned page is 8.5x11", the size of the scanner bed.

For much smaller PDF files I could throw it into Photoshop and crop the page, but this is a huge file. What is the best way to losslessly crop all of the pages of the file, in either Windows or OS X?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two products that do PDF crop:

[PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer)
Commercial with trial.

[PDFill PDF Tools](http://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html)
Completely free.

I haven't used them, so do not know if they do crop all the pages at once.

Comment: PDFFill worked great. It seemed spywary at first, but it does what it says.

Comment: Do you know of any command line tool that does the same job?  This should help scripting.

Comment: Hmm, PDFill PDF Tools added watermarks for me...

Answer (score 2):

[PDF Scissors](http://www.pdfscissors.com/) apparently is designed for the sole purpose of PDF cropping.

Key Features inc.

- No installation required. Just click the start button,
- Take those extra margins aways with easy cropping tool!
- Avoid accidentally cropping some texts
- Scanned book? Crop odd/even pages separately
- Complex pdf? Crop individual pages separately with full freedom.
- Create crop areas easily

The website includes a short introductory video as well.

Comment: Note that PDF Scissors, unlike pdfcrop, does not allow automatic border detection: it works similarly to Briss, allowing you to specify the cropping rectangle(s), but it does not detect it automatically.

Comment: The website is down, so don't click the link.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem. I found PDFill PDF Tools to be quite user unfriendly. An alternative that worked for me was to use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/). Nice and intuitive, lots of online tutorials and it's free!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [www.cutepdf-editor.com](http://www.cutepdf-editor.com) and you'll have your pages cropped the way you want!!!
It's free, it's online, without any installation at your PC.
I've just used it and I'm happy with the result.